# Blazor EditForm with custom fluent validator, remove rule while updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, fluentvalidation, blazor-server-side

I have custom validator

```
RuleFor(d => d.Id).NotEmpty()
            .Matches("^[0-9]*$")
            .WithMessage("Id must consist of number!")
            .MustAsync(async (id, token) =>
            {
                // make http request

                if (someCase)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }).WithMessage("Some error");
```

And using it in EditForm as

```
<FluentValidationValidator ValidatorType=typeof(MyValidator) />
```

disabling the button

```
EditContext = new EditContext(MyModel);
EditContext.OnFieldChanged += async (sender, e) =>
{
   IsInvalidForm = !(await Validator.ValidateAsync(MyModel)).IsValid;
   StateHasChanged();
};
```

So far so good, it works, but while updating (using the same Razor component) the Id field is **disabled** and if I change some other value part of the validator, it also checks the Id and returns **IsValid** false (because it already exists). How can I fix that?

Answer (score -1):

Adding a state to your validator should work

```cs
private bool _isValid;
RuleFor(d => d.Id).NotEmpty()
            .Matches("^[0-9]*$")
            .WithMessage("Id must consist of number!")
            .MustAsync(async (id, token) =>
            {
                if (_isValid)
                {
                   return true;
                }
                // make http request

                if (someCase)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                _isValid = true;
                return true;
            }).WithMessage("Some error");
```